# Select vertex sequence based on a vector -- bibcoupling

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph with thousands of vertices ("authors") and edges ("citations"). I want to calculate for a **specific subset** of authors the bibliographic coupling (cmd: bibcoupling); to select the subset I plan to use a vector including the authors of interest.

How can I select the vertex sequence of interest using a vector?

```
rm(list=ls())
library("igraph")

g <- make_ring(10) %>%
set_vertex_attr("label", value = letters[1:10])

#Vertex sequence of interest
s_lab<-c("a","b","f") 
s_ind<-c(1,2,6)

#I would like to replicate these outputs using the vectors s_lab and s_ind
bibcoupling(g,v=V(g)[label=="a" | label== "b" | label=="f"])
bibcoupling(g,v=V(g)[1,2,6])
```

Many thanks for your inputs, I highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to use the `s_lab` or `s_ind` objects in your subsetting of the graph instead of the long hard coded expression in between the `[`s. If so, then something like this does the trick:

```
bibcoupling(g,v=V(g)[label %in% s_lab])
bibcoupling(g,v=V(g)[s_ind])
```

Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot.